# Relative Import --- Ultimate Version

Tags: python, python-import, relative-import

```
|-- eval.py
|-- modeling_llama.py
|-- patch
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- flash_attn.py
|   |-- log_scale.py
|   |-- ntk.py
|   |-- ntk_fixed.py
|   |-- ntk_mixed.py
|   `-- rerope.py
|-- prompt.py
|-- test_model.sh
`-- utils.py
```

Above is my project directory.

The script I run is `eval.py`, which imports `utils.py`. `patch` is imported to `utils.py`. `patch.rerope` depends on `modelling_llama`, so I have to import `modelling_llama` in `rerope`. I'm confused about how I can correctly import `modelling_llama` in `rerope` since it's a repository level higher.

Should I be `import modelling_llama`, `from .. import modelling_llama`, or `import ..modeling_llama`.

I've tried all the above and found merely `import modelling_llama` work fine for me, but I'm still wondering why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through several questions regarding **relative import** or **python-import**, all of them provided useful information, but none of them gave me a clear whole picture of how to use **python-import**.

After reading Python documentation and related PEP, and doing some necessary experiments, I think I've got a clear picture of this issue. While I may still miss some corner cases, I share my findings here and hope it's useful.

##### Import convention

Before we dive into details, let's first classify **python-import**.

All `import` statements are ***absolute import*** by default.

Only special syntax (**leading dots**, e.g. `from ..modelling_llama import module_x`) leads to ***relative imports***.

##### Absolute Imports

Absolute imports search from ***sys.path***.

> Which is initialized upon program startup, a potentially unsafe path is prepended to it:
>
> - `python -m module` command line: prepend the ***current working directory.***
> - `python script.py` command line: prepend ***the script’s directory***. If it’s a symbolic link, resolve symbolic links.
> - `python -c code` and `python` (REPL) command lines: prepend an empty string, which means the current working directory.

This paragraph is from Python Documentation, but it only talks about how `sys.path` is initialized. But how will `sys.path` change for each imported file? After simple experiments, I've come to the conclusion that except for the main script whose `sys.path` is initialized the way above, all the subsequent imported modules will inherit this `sys.path` and only look for packages from this path.

This perfectly answers my question of why merely `import modelling_llama` works well.

##### Relative Imports

Relative imports use a module’s __*name__* attribute to determine that module’s position in the package hierarchy.

For how to determine the `__name__` attribute, [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) is quite clear.

In short:

> - If it was loaded as the top-level script, its name is `__main__`.
> - If it was loaded as a module, its name is [the filename, preceded by the names of any packages/subpackages of which it is a part, separated by dots], for example, `package.subpackage1.moduleX`.

This again perfectly explains why `from ..modeling_llama import module_x` will fail. Since the name of this `rerope` module is `patch.rerope`, `..` will lead to `beyond top level package error in relative import`, which makes sense.

So what if I insisted on using relative imports? Adding another folder level to match `..` should work fine!

Comment: See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76966957/281545) by Blckknght - you should be using the -m switch

Answer (score 3):

Relative imports only make sense *within a package*. This can be confusing if you *think* you have your code in a package, but the Python interpreter doesn't see it that way.

In your current project, Python sees `eval`, `modeling_llama`, `util` and the other top-level things in your file structure are seen as top level modules. This happens because of how you're running your script. The top-level folder is getting added to `sys.path` (as is explained by one of the quotes you have in your answer). If you think these should be in a package (named after whatever the top-level folder is named), you need to run your code from one folder further up (with `python -m my_package.eval` perhaps).

If both `modeling_llama` and `patch.rerope` are part of the same top-level package (with `patch` being a sub-package), then you can use the relative import you were trying out. This will require you to change *all your other* `import` statements too, as `import util` won't work from `eval` if they're both in a package (and thus not accessible as top-level module names). If `modeling_llama` really should be a top-level module, then you *must* import it as such, with `import modeling_llama` (or `from modeling_llama import whatever`, if you don't need a reference to the module itself).

Answer (score -1):

you should add the directory path to environment

use this codes

**rerope.py**

```
import os
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
filename = os.sep.join(abspath.split(os.sep)[-2:])
abspath = abspath.replace(filename, "")
import sys
sys.path.append(abspath)

import modelling_llama
```

**eval.py**

```
import os
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
filename = abspath.split(os.sep)[-1]
abspath = abspath.replace(filename, "")
import sys
sys.path.append(abspath)

import modelling_llama
```